# Creating SOAP XML request PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, web-services, soap

I've been working on a solution to link our Point of Sale applications (Java and MySQL based) to our ERP system. I've made a PHP front-end for the database where you can see all of the transactions that need to be sent over. Now I create a SOAP request to our ERP system based on the MySQL records. I don't have a clue how I should go about this. I know that the SOAP request needs to have **all** of the transactions, or else all of the entries won't be in balance. (Credit/Debit needs to be the same.)

All of the required fields in the SOAP request are available inside the database, so I just need to know how to create 1 XML request with all of the transactions. (Filtered by date, but that's done in the database.)

Here is a example SOAP request with 1 transactions consisting of 3 rows in the database (Credit/Debit is already separated in the DB):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Execute>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:token><![CDATA[<token><version>1</version><data>TOKEN-ALWAYS THE SAME</data></token>]]></urn:token>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:connectorType>FiEntries</urn:connectorType>
         <urn:connectorVersion>1</urn:connectorVersion>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:dataXml><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FiEntryPar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Element>
    <Fields Action="insert">
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Peri>7</Peri>
      <JoCo>01</JoCo>
    </Fields>
    <Objects>
      <FiEntries>
        <Element>
          <Fields Action="insert">
            <VaAs>2</VaAs>
            <AcNr>10002</AcNr>
            <EnDa>2017-07-21</EnDa>
            <BpDa>2017-07-21</BpDa>
            <BpNr>346</BpNr>
            <InId>346</InId>
            <Ds>20b8be4b-20b2-4d16-a079-7720404cdf4c</Ds>
            <AmDe>20</AmDe>
            <AmCr>0</AmCr>
          </Fields>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <Fields Action="insert">
            <VaAs>1</VaAs>
            <AcNr>8100</AcNr>
            <EnDa>2017-07-21</EnDa>
            <BpDa>2017-07-21</BpDa>
            <BpNr>346</BpNr>
            <InId>346</InId>
            <Ds>20b8be4b-20b2-4d16-a079-7720404cdf4c</Ds>
            <AmDe>0</AmDe>
            <AmCr>16.53</AmCr>
            <VaId>1</VaId>
          </Fields>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <Fields Action="insert">
            <VaAs>1</VaAs>
            <AcNr>1510</AcNr>
            <EnDa>2017-07-21</EnDa>
            <BpDa>2017-07-21</BpDa>
            <BpNr>346</BpNr>
            <InId>346</InId>
            <Ds>20b8be4b-20b2-4d16-a079-7720404cdf4c</Ds>
            <AmDe>0</AmDe>
            <AmCr>3.47</AmCr>
            <VaId>1</VaId>
          </Fields>
        </Element>
      </FiEntries>
    </Objects>
  </Element>
</FiEntryPar>]]>
</urn:dataXml>
      </urn:Execute>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[This is how the database looks and which fields go where in the request:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfrTA.png)

WSDL from the SOAPui:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:Execute>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:token>?</urn:token>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:connectorType>?</urn:connectorType>
         <urn:connectorVersion>?</urn:connectorVersion>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:dataXml>?</urn:dataXml>
      </urn:Execute>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Soap comes with WSDL in which the possible functions and how the request should look are defined. Anyway: what is the question? And are you using php's SoapClient?

Comment: I want to know how to make a XML like this using the data in MySQL using PHP. They do not provide a WSDL.

Comment: You will have an url where to send the xml to. What if you put "wsdl" or "?wsdl" behind it?

Comment: You'll get a WSDL-type. It's the above XML but without the dataXML piece.

Comment: But to continue on your question. Do you want all records on some boekingsdatum sent to to the soap server? Or only those with the same boekstuknummers? Simplest approach is to just select those records from mysql and place them in the xml-layout. However: there is a risk on charakters like < in your input. So if not using soapclient, i would at least go for php's xml functions

Comment: Afas? That's not the smalles player in the market. I suppose they will have a descend description of the wsdl available.

Comment: They have a lot of documentation online: https://kb.afas.nl/index.php/details/kb/product:se//?0100000064179010129720160202#connector

Comment: I've seen the documentation, and I've requested the WSDL from SoapUI. You'll get the following XML back, without any of the fields that you need to fill in. (see post)

Comment: Normally you don 't have to deal with the xml compiling. Compiling takes the soap client / soap server. The only thing you have to know is what kind of data the several soap methods demand. For this the PHP soap client got the method `SoapClient::__getFunctions()`. All functions are marked with a return type and the parameters they take. These types you can get via `SoapClient::__getTypes()`. At this point you know the soap methods and the soap types connected to these methods. Just build up entites and map them in the classmap option for the SoapClient constructor.

Comment: Can you provide the wsdl address for a quick example?